# Combining Chrome Options and Capabilities?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Combining Chrome Options and Capabilities?

I have tried the following below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<Path to binary>");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
webdriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version of ChromeDriver 2.28 fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the combination of options does not make sense, becouse:

```
    if chrome_options is None:
        # desired_capabilities stays as passed in
        if desired_capabilities is None:
            desired_capabilities = self.create_options().to_capabilities()
    else:
        if desired_capabilities is None:
            desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities()
        else:
            desired_capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

This behavior is defined in the method of init.